# Invalid Hook call in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I'm quite new to react and get the following error:

```
react-dom.development.js:14906 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

I want to use another component when a form is submit. so in file A when the form is submit, is uses a function where is first checks something before calling the other component like:

```
ComponentName()
```

On the component I have some useState hooks:

```
function ComponentName() {
    const [state1, setState1] = useState('')
    const [state2, setState2] = useState('')
    const [state3, setState3] = useState('')
```

at the moment the page is loading i am getting this error, does anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: To show either component A or component B (or hide/show a component) you use conditional rendering; you don't call component functions yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You don't call component functions, you give them to React and let React call them as appropriate. So you'd never write `ComponentName()` in your code. Instead, you'd use `<ComponentName />` as part of rendering another component or, for the very top-level of the React tree, as part of the JSX you're passing `ReactDOM.render`. (Or of course, use `React.createElement` rather than JSX.)

You're getting the error because if you *call* the component function as you've shown, it's not being used as a component, so your calls to hooks have no component instance to use behind the scenes — hence the error message.

Comment: I tried different ways to call ComponentName, the thing is, with the ComponentName() way, is the only way its shows me something. if I use <ComponentName/>, nothing shows up

Comment: @Kwiznix - Work through some React tutorials. If `ComponentName` is your top-level component, for instance, you'd use `ReactDOM.render(<ComponentName/>, document.getElementById("root"));` (assuming you have an element with `id="root"` in your HTML where you want your React tree to be rooted). If you're using bootstrapping projects like Create React App, they may have done that work for you (in `index.jsx` or `index.tsx`, in the case of CRA, which assumes the root of your app is a component called `App` in the file `App.jsx`/`App.tsx`).

Comment: Yes I have a index.js file, this file has `ReactDOM.render(), document.getElementByID("root"));`. In this file I use react-router-dom to route to the different pages, on one of those pages there is a form, and when the form is submitted I want to do something with the results of that form, so I want to call the 'ComponentName' to do stuff there, so the form has a `onSubmit: functionName` and the function is like `const functionName = () => {<ComponentName/>}`, when I use that, the console.logs in the `ComponentName` file wont show up in the console